# My "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is not working in my .htaccess?

Tags: javascript, cors, apache2

While I was trying to get information from the "https://api.steampowered.com" API I was getting the error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=<<MyKEY>>&steamid=<<MySteamID>>' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Then I set the `AllowOverride` to `all` in my `apache2.conf`and added the header `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://api.steampowered.com"` to my .htaccess located in `/var/www/html`.
(I also tryed it with `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`)
I enabled the a2enmod headers with `a2enmod headers` after that I restarted my webserver with `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.
But it still doesn't work.

My .htaccess:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

My apache2.conf:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=<<MyKEY>>&steamid=<<MySteamID>>', function (data) {
        //My code with the data
    });
});
```

Maybe I need to put the header elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a webpage, `https://example.com/` which includes some JavaScript.

That JavaScript wants to read data from `https://api.steampowered.com/`.

To do this, `https://api.steampowered.com/` needs to give permission to `https://example.com`.

You have configured `https://example.com` to grant permission to all websites to read data from it.

You haven't configured `https://api.steampowered.com/` to grant permission to anyone. (At least I assume you don't work for Steam).

Comment: Thank you! Good to know that :)